# Suppose $M$ is $n \times p$ of rank r and that $M$ is partitioned as [A, B \\C, D] where $A$ is $r \times r$ of rank r. Show that $D = CA^{-1}B$.

Tags: matrices

Suppose $M$ is $n \times p$ of rank r and that $M$ is partitioned as 
 \begin{bmatrix}
       A & B \\[0.3em]
       C & D           
     \end{bmatrix}
where $A$ is $r \times r$ of rank r. Show that $D = CA^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: an elementary transformation gives
$$\begin{bmatrix}
       A & B \\[0.3em]
       C & D           
     \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
       A & B \\[0.3em]
       O & D-CA^{-1}B           
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
while not changing the rank.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the rank for this problem

Comment: @user136266 what is the rank of M and what is the rank of A?

Comment: both r? isnt that stated?

Comment: @user136266 now they have equal ranks, what can you say about $D-CA^{-1}B$?

Comment: That the column vectors in [A // 0] actually spans the column space of M such that $[B // D-CA^{-1}B]$ can be formed by  [A//0]u for some u so $D-CA^{-1}B = 0$?

Comment: @user136266 you are right.